# Can not get Virtualizor IP pool working with /27 subnet

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, subnet

I've been scratching my head a few days at this now and I am by no means a networking expert but I know (most) of the basics.

I've got Virtualizor setup on CentOS 7 and I'm trying to add a new /27 (216.x.x.0/27) I got from my hosting company. My servers main IP is the first available IP in the subnet (216.x.x.2), the rest of the IPs should go to any VPS that gets spun up.

So far the furthest I've gotten with this is: I can ping vps ip inside server but not outside. SSH is not available at all in server or outside.

When configuring IP Pool in Virtualizor I have the NAT option checked. This creates a libvirt network (mine is called natbr3). It starts fine, sometimes I have to start service firewalld before hand. For the gateway, it is the first IP of my subnet (216.x.x.1). For first available IP I have 216.x.x.3 and for last I have 216.x.x.30. For the netmask I put 255.255.255.224.

IP Pool Settings 
GATEWAY: 216.x.x.1 
NETMASK: 255.255.255.224 
IP POOL: 216.x.x.3 - 216.x.x.30 (28)

My server is only using one connection called eno1 and the ifcfg-eno1 is as follows:

```
DEVICE=eno1
HWADDR=xx:c4:xx:c4:xx:14
IPV6INIT=no
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=216.x.x.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
GATEWAY=216.x.x.1
PREFIX=32
DEFROUTE=yes
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=1.1.1.1
```

Im not positive by all means but I'm starting to wonder if my main server IP needs to be outside of the subnet. I put the server IP as a /32 to be able to use the correct netmask in the IP pool settings (natbr3 gets these settings), this is the only way I'm able to ping the vps inside the server (outside still does not work).

I know this may be a shot in the dark and I've tried to be as precise with the information I've given in my question. If there is any more information need please ask!
Thank you for taking the time to read this and any help you may have to offer.

**EDIT** 
I should mention I can access the VPS with VNC and inside the VPS I can ping the gateway but nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Come to find out, the server main IP being inside the /27 subnet is a issue and will cause Virtualizor IP Pool to not function properly. I have got that resolved by getting a dedicated IP for the main server IP.